# Spring Injection not working between Ejb jar and WAR in websphere liberty server

Tags: spring

I am migrating websphere application server to websphere liberty server. We are using enterprise application , which contains EAR with ebj module and WAR (web application) developed using spring , some classes from ejb module and injected in WAR module, the classes are able to inject without any issue in websphere server but this architecture is not working in liberty server. I am getting null for injection properties. Do i need to do any additional conifiguration for liberty sever. Thanks

EAR 
|- helloworldejb.jar
|
|- helloworldwebapp

Thanks,
Siva Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Actually in liberty server the EAR/WAR applications are lazy loading which means the application will load only when the request receives which is not in the case of Websphere application server. So here the required injection properties are injected in WAR level and the WAR module will only load when request receives and then inject the properties. So for the first time when EAR module receives the request , WAR module will not load during this time, . If we want to stop lazy loading then we need to have the below configuration in sever.xml , which helps to load all the initialization during startup of the server. Find the below configuration details and documentation related to the configuration.

Config details :

```
    <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>
```

URL :

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_servlet_load.html